# USe LINQ to remove from a list based on conditions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq

I have a list 'nList' returned from a LINQ query. The data is correct but I have to check if the data in the 2nd field ('nType') occurs more than once, and if it does, remove it from the list if the 3rd field ('nAmount') is null.
To illustrate, in the example below, I would want to remove the record with ID 2.
Can this be done using LINQ?

EDIT: There can only be 2 scenarios:

1. one occurrence of nType, with nAmount populated
2. two occurences of nType, with one nAmount populated, the other nAmount null

---

```
ID  nType     nAmount
1   A         12.00
2   A          
3   B         13.00
4   C         14.00
```

Comment: What if there are three `nType=A` and 2 of them are not null for `nAmount`?

Comment: There will only ever be at most 2, and if there are 2 one will be null

Comment: What if an `nAmount` is `null` while there´s only one element with that `nType`? Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = nList.Where(x => x.nAmount != null).DistinctBy(x => x.nType);
```

You would need to install MoreLinq from Nuget to get the `DistinctBy()`.

Comment: I'm not even the owner of this and I'd like to know why it was marked down.

Comment: Ill mark you up ;-) to get you back to neutral, as i think this is valid. I think you should expand but defo not a mark down.

Comment: @Seabizkit Thanks, I also think that this is good solution for the problem, without diving into grouping etc...Maybe the one interested could give it a try?

Comment: I like this approach, but I should have mentioned (only just found out to be fair) that if I have one occurrence of nType, it should be included in the list whether nAmount is null or not

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a `GroupBy` overload which lets you define the grouped object

```
var result = nList.GroupBy(
                   x => x.nType, 
                   (key,g) => new { 
                       ID = g.First(x => x.nAmount != null).ID, 
                       nType = key, 
                       nAmount = g.First(x => x.nAmount != null).nAmount }
             );
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/PFX41986

This has a few caveats

- If your resultset has a single `nType` which has a null `nAmount` it will not appear in the results
- If you get more than 1 distinct `nType` with a non-null `nAmount` this will take the first one.

Comment: FirstOrDefault for nAmount? What if there isn't one without null? Oh, nevermind, just seen the above comment

Comment: @MikeyMouse And the .nAmount will still throw null reference exception if that is the case. Only g.FirstOrDefault(x => x.nAmount != null)?.nAmount. Will do what you want.

Comment: Yeah, can't wait to use C# 6.0 at work and not have to do the whole == null ? 0 : x thing

Comment: Thanks for all the input, I'll accept an answer shortly, but they all seem good and make sense